# Why does Power BI not allow multi path filtering?

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://www.vivran.in/post/understanding-ambiguity-in-power-bi-data-model

[image]
[image]

1. In above example why does the Path 2 need to be inactive? Isn't Power BI able to filter the Target table using both the paths?
2. If I apply DAX USERELATIONSHIP then will Power BI choose only the specified path? And ignore the other path?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple paths aren't allowed because they would make the model difficult to use.  If a report writer selects a Manager, would they expect to see the Manager's targets, or the Manager's Customer's targets?  Typically one or the other, and as the model designer you must choose which.

Otherwise how would the filter work?  Would it be the union of the two sets?  The intersection?

And yes USERELATIONSHIP allows you to write measures using an inactive relationship.

Comment: If I did want both sides to filter the fact then is there a way? For example: AND logic.

Comment: The most common solution is to duplicate the Manager table and have two slicers.